# Proper way to do logging for iOS device level VPN (NEPacketTunnelProvider)

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, vpn

My app has a device level VPN extension, and I am currently logging to the console with NSLog() files. However, I would like to have some persistent logging so I can track problems that happened earlier in time.

Normally, I would write logs to a temp or documents directory, and then I could pull that off with something like iExplore.

However, it seem that VPN extensions are in a different container, so I can't do this.

Any suggestions how I can do persistent logging?

Answer (score 0):

You can still write to a file and read it later.
I did it with CocoaLumberjack -  https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack